# Add class to body when url changes using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I'm using a plugin in ajax that filter some products of my site.
The url changes without reload the page.

I need indentify the url, split the words and add those class to body.

E.G: I filter some products, then my url changes to https://website.com/size=big/color=yellow,green,dark-red
So, this classes would be added to body: size big color yellow green dark-red

I have this code but I don't know how to make it work.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
       $('body'). 
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1520-binding-events-to-non-dom-objects-with-jquery.htm

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Based on the comment thread in my answer it seems that you're really trying to convert the querystring values to css class names.

You can use the `window.location.search` to access all the querystring parameters.

```
function updateBodyClasses() {

  var classNames = [];

  // Use `.split()` to separate each key/value pair in the query by `&`
  window.location.search.split('&')
    // and loop over the results
    .forEach(function(c) {

      // Now split each pair by '='
      var pair = c.split['='];

      // Add the value to the left of the '=' 
      if (pair.length > 0) {
        classNames.push(pair[0]);

        // if there are values on the right of the '='...
        if (pair.length > 1) {

          // ... split them by ',' and loop through them
          pair[1].split(',').forEach(function(t) {
            classNames.push(t);
          });      
        }
      }
    });

    // Now append those classNames to the body
    $('body').addClass(classNames.join(' '));
}

// If your ajax plugin modifies the url via HTML5 history api...
$(window).on('popstate', updateBodyClasses);


// Update classes on page load
$(window).on('load', updateBodyClasses);

// If the ajax plugin modifies the url using window.location.replace()
// you'll need to check on an interval whether things have changed
// and update accordingly. the following example does this every 1000 milliseconds (or every second)

setInterval(updateBodyClasses, 1000);
```

Comment: I put your code inside $(window).on('hashchange', function(e){ I did right?

Comment: Yes, I actually just updated my answer to do the same.

Comment: It doesn't load the changes, but if I manually reload the page it does. And here is the class that was added ?filter_cor=amarelo,azul,vermelho - have no spaces. Please help.

Comment: Why are you using `hashchange` ?  Is there a `#` symbol in your url?

Comment: I tried $(document).ready(function() { did not work. See my site (tab "Cores"): https://3brow.com/loja/?filter_cor=verde

Comment: So now, in your most recent url you're showing, you have a `?` in it. These details are important!